# Check if salted Hashed User ID exists

Tags: java, sql, database, hash, salt

Set-up...Java, SQL, & ID cards that for some silly reason all start with 1000 followed by 6 numbers. These IDs are salted & hashed prior to storage. An ID will be stored only when mail is received and that item is assigned a mailbox. There will be at most 100 mailboxes and an item may have several valid ID's.

Let's assume 100*3, we could have 300 salted hashes in a db.

What would be the most concise way of taking a user's ID to compare if there is a mail for that user. It seems like, pulling down all 300 salts to generate a 300 hashes to validate is laborious.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why you're hashing ID card numbers and salting them.  Salt is used to stop an attacker using rainbow tables and password lists.  In order to compare hashes though, you store the plain salt with the hash.  But your ID numbers seem to have very very little entropy, so I'm not sure the purpose of all of this.

Comment: I share your same thoughts on "why do we have to hash ID numbers", BUT that is what is required so I still am still looking for a more concise way to process this info.  Although 300 hashes may seem small, I still have to concern my self with growing this at scale.

Comment: Normally, you  have an ID for the hash that allows you to do only one comparison.  I'm guessing you don't have an ID for the ID number.  So if you can't store an unsalted hash or the plain text ID anywhere, then I think you're out of luck.  I'd recommend looking into why a salted hashed ID number is a requirement, and see if there's a way of not doing it.